# Automate getting a JSON URL and commit to a git repository?

Tags: json, git, curl

I need to read an existing URL of a JSON document, save it to a file, and commit that file to a git repo on a daily schedule. This seems easier than it's appearing so far, to me.

I'm assuming some sort of Cron job or scheduler, but I haven't been able to find a good solution.

Comment: I don't understand, please clarify. You have and URL pointing to a JSON file. You want to download the file and commit it. Right? What OS? `cron` is for Unix/Linux, scheduler is for w32.

Comment: I will set up whatever is the best situation for this task. I have a web server on Unix now however I can also set up Heroku scheduler if needed as well.

But yes, I want to access the URL, grab the code located there and commit it as a file to my git repo on Github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution seems to be rather simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
cd /path/to/repository
curl -LOR http://$URL/file.json  # download the file
git add file.json
git commit -m "file.json at $(date +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

`file.json` is just a placeholder, put the real filename in your script. `date +%Y-%m-%d` generates the current date for commit message.

You can use `wget` instead of `curl`:

```
wget -O file.json http://$URL/file.json
```

Make the script executable and call it from cron:

```
0 9 * * * /path/to/the/script
```

This calls the script at 9:00 every day.